# Laravel model foreach new instance fatal error Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, model

```
use App\Abc\Model1;
use App\Abc\Model2;
use App\Abc\Model3;
use App\Abc\Model4;

// This My Models

$modelArr = ['Model1','Model2','Model3','Model4'];
          foreach ($modelArr as $key => $value) {
              $model = new $value;
              $model->where('abc','=',$abc)->get();
              $model->delete();
          }
```

// But not working fatal error : Model1 Class Not Found

Comment: Here `'Model1', 'Model2', ...` are not instances of that models, they are just a string  variable. use `new Model1, new Model2, ...` instead.

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$modelArr = [Model1::class,Model2::class,Model3::class,Model4::class];
```

Or if you need to assign with string you need to include full namespace to the strings.
Example:

```
$modelArr = ['App\Model1','App\Model2','App\Model3','App\Model4'];
```

- please let me know what errors are showing

Comment: i was added Model1::class. Perfect Working.thank you